# How to connect my wifi with command or some software on my debian8?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

There are two computers in my room.
A  is connected to wireless router +adsl modem ,gateway is 192.168.1.1 ,localhost is 192.168.1.100.Security Options is none

The pci wifi receiver was installed on computer B.
My android phone can connect wifi .
In computer B(os debian8)'s console,

```
iw dev wlan0 scan
TSF: 44377007236 usec (0d, 12:19:37)
freq: 2452
beacon interval: 100 TUs
capability: ESS Privacy ShortPreamble ShortSlotTime (0x0431)
signal: -59.00 dBm
last seen: 0 ms ago
Information elements from Probe Response frame:
SSID: MyCharterWiFi99-2G
Supported rates: 1.0* 2.0* 5.5* 11.0* 6.0 9.0 12.0 18.0
DS Parameter set: channel 9
```

It means that wifi signal send out by wireless router can be scanned by computer B.
No error info when to input  `iw wlan0 connect  MyCharterWiFi99-2G  2452`  command in console of computer B.
, but nothing in my firefox when to input some urls.
How to connect the  SSID: MyCharterWiFi99-2G  with no password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iw dev connect` is needed, but it's a low-level tool that merely *associates* to the Wi-Fi network, **similar to connecting a wired Ethernet cable**. However that's not enough for "inputting some urls" – you also need to have an IP address, and configured some DNS servers.

The simplest method usually would be to use NetworkManager or something similar, and let it obtain necessary configuration from DHCP – either you can just select the Wi-Fi network from a list (like Windows) or use `nmcli` or `nmtui` to connect:

```
nmcli dev wifi connect MyCharterWiFi99-2G
```

Of course you can run a DHCP client by hand:

```
iw wlan0 connect -w MyCharterWiFi99-2G
dhclient wlan0
```

The completely manual method:

```
iw wlan0 connect -w MyCharterWiFi99-2G
ip addr add 192.168.1.123/24 dev wlan0
ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0
echo "nameserver 192.168.1.1" > /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: why 192.168.1.1 can't ping after all four lines executed?

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13091085/

Comment: Probably because you forgot the netmask (`/24`) when adding the IP address.

Comment: To set `iface eth0 inet dhcp` in  /etc/network/interfaces of computer B,done,computer B can connect any urls now.

Comment: when to change the wifi router into wap2=psk mode, how to connect it with wpa_supplicant ?  http://superuser.com/questions/995793/why-the-wpa2-psk-wifi-cant-be-connected