# Why the WPA2-PSK wifi can't be connected?

Tags: wireless-networking

The ssid name is MyCharterWiFi99-2G,Security Options :None ,
WPA2-PSK [AES] ,Passphrase :  happygiant682,my os is debian8.

```
cat  /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
network={
    ssid="MyCharterWiFi99-2G"
    psk="happygiant682"
}

#wpa_supplicant -B -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
# iw wlan0 link
Not connected.
```

No error info when to execute wpa_supplicant command,Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant,why not connected?
Some error info occur when to run wpa_supplicant in debug mode.

```
wpa_supplicant  -D nl80211  -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 04:a1:51:ba:6a:99 (SSID='MyCharterWiFi99-2G' freq=2417 MHz)
wlan0: Trying to associate with 04:a1:51:ba:6a:99 (SSID='MyCharterWiFi99-2G' freq=2417 MHz)
wlan0: Associated with 04:a1:51:ba:6a:99
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=04:a1:51:ba:6a:99 reason=3 locally_generated=1
wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 04:a1:51:ba:6a:99 (SSID='MyCharterWiFi99-2G' freq=2417 MHz)
wlan0: Trying to associate with 04:a1:51:ba:6a:99 (SSID='MyCharterWiFi99-2G' freq=2417 MHz)
wlan0: Associated with 04:a1:51:ba:6a:99
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=04:a1:51:ba:6a:99 reason=3 locally_generated=1
wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 04:a1:51:ba:6a:99 (SSID='MyCharterWiFi99-2G' freq=2417 MHz)
wlan0: Trying to associate with 04:a1:51:ba:6a:99 (SSID='MyCharterWiFi99-2G' freq=2417 MHz)
wlan0: Associated with 04:a1:51:ba:6a:99
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=04:a1:51:ba:6a:99 reason=3 locally_generated=1
wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 04:a1:51:ba:6a:99 (SSID='MyCharterWiFi99-2G' freq=2417 MHz)
wlan0: Trying to associate with 04:a1:51:ba:6a:99 (SSID='MyCharterWiFi99-2G' freq=2417 MHz)
wlan0: Associated with 04:a1:51:ba:6a:99
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=04:a1:51:ba:6a:99 reason=3 locally_generated=1
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="MyCharterWiFi99-2G" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=CONN_FAILED
```

Comment: Have you tried running wpa_supplicant in debug mode, without the `-B`? Maybe even with `-d`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sovled with the form of /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-driver nl80211
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

Reboot,go surfing now.

Comment: I don't know why it works, but it works! :) The only thing I also changed was to put the `psk` in plaintext instead of the hash.

Comment: It worked here, thanks ;-) ... Ah, not needed to issue the wpa-driver line ... Long whole day suffering with this

Comment: BTW instead reboot, use **service networking restart** ... it saves time